# Can Napi::Env be shared with multi-threads?

Tags: node.js

I want to use Napi::Env object in multi-threads. 
 Can I achieve it?

An error occurs when shared with global variables, the error is as follows:

```
# Fatal error in v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle()
# Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope
```